# how to customise AppRTC to receive call

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo, signaling, apprtc

I have integrated **AppRTC** in my project and I am able to join the WebRTC call in the room of https://apprtc.appspot.com using RoomName

```
    appClient = ARDAppClient(delegate: self)
    appClient?.createLocalMediaStream()
    appClient?.connectToRoomWithId(String(roomId), options: nil)
```

[image: AppRtc]

I am able to hardcode a *RoomName* in my app and install the app in two *devices A & B* and if I make a call from both the devices at same time in A & B then I am able to *successfully have a WebRTC call between them*.

Now I'd like to do a real VOIP call that is make a call from my app in device A and receive the call at my app in device B.

AFAIK I have to do SIGNALING part right here to connect to the app in device B from device A.

Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: I think it's better to be more specific. Are you asking whether WebRTC has a signaling or are you asking how to build one (outside of WebRTC)?

Comment: @VictorRonin - I have signaling library with me but how to discover the app in device B...and how to send call offer to that device B and how to receive the call in device B and accept it ? this shows the libs http://imgur.com/8sRf1H0

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `signaling server`. Both peers connect to it and they can negotiate a room name through it before starting a call. When a room name is decided, both peers can simply connect to that room and they will be able to see each other.

There are a few signaling servers designed for WebRTC available online or you can make your own, it's not that complex. Really all it needs to do is register clients and act as a mailman between them.

Comment: How to use the AppRTC library to connect with signaling server and do the negotiation to make this possible ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H You will have to do that yourself, the AppRTC demo is really only meant to verify that the library works, not to extend and build your app with.

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Also, since I'm getting tons of upvotes suddenly on my WebRTC answers, I assume that's you? Please don't do this, the system will take them away anyway ;)